# How do you predict outcomes from a new dataset using a model created from a different dataset in R?

Tags: r, linear-regression, predict

I could be missing something about prediction -- but my multiple linear regression is seemingly working as expected:

```
> bigmodel <- lm(score ~ lean + gender + age, data = mydata)
> summary(bigmodel)

Call:
lm(formula = score ~ lean + gender + age, data = mydata)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-25.891  -4.354   0.892   6.240  18.537 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 70.96455    3.85275  18.419   <2e-16 ***
lean         0.62463    0.05938  10.518   <2e-16 ***
genderM     -2.24025    1.40362  -1.596   0.1121    
age          0.10783    0.06052   1.782   0.0764 .  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 9 on 195 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.4188,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.4098 
F-statistic: 46.83 on 3 and 195 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

> head(predict(bigmodel),20)
       1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9       10 
75.36711 74.43743 77.02533 78.76903 79.95515 79.09251 80.38647 81.65807 80.14846 78.96234 
      11       12       13       14       15       16       17       18       19       20 
82.39052 82.04468 81.05187 81.26753 84.50240 81.80667 80.92169 82.40895 81.76197 82.94809
```

But I can't wrap my head around the prediction after reading `?predict.lm`. This output looks good to me for my original dataset -- but what if I want to run the prediction against a *different* dataset than the one I used to create `bigmodel`?

For example, if I import a .csv file into R called `newmodel` with 200 people complete with leans, gender, and age -- how can I use the regression formula from `bigmodel` to produce predictions for `newmodel`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the documentation for `predict.lm`, you will see the following. So, use the `newdata` argument to pass the `newmodel` data you imported to get predictions.

```
predict(object, newdata, se.fit = FALSE, scale = NULL, df = Inf,
        interval = c("none", "confidence", "prediction"),
        level = 0.95, type = c("response", "terms"),
        terms = NULL, na.action = na.pass,
        pred.var = res.var/weights, weights = 1, ...)
Arguments

object  
Object of class inheriting from "lm"

newdata 
An optional data frame in which to look for variables with which to predict. 
If omitted, the fitted values are used.
```

UPDATE. On the question of exporting data with predictions, here is how you can do it.

```
predictions = cbind(newmodel, pred = predict(bigmodel, newdata = newmodel))
write.csv(predictions, 'predictions.csv', row.names = F)
```

UPDATE 2. A full minimally reproducible solution

```
bigmodel <- lm(mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars)
newdata = data.frame(wt = runif(20, min = 1.5, max = 6))

cbind(
  newdata,
  mpg = predict(bigmodel, newdata = newdata)
)
```

Comment: Ah! I was missing something. Thanks! I saw the `newdata` but thought it referred to an actual dataframe, rather than an argument. But it's actually both -- right? So I'd have to upload what I initially called `newmodel` as `newdata` and then it works.

Comment: Also, is there a way to more easily export the prediction into a column in Excel? Or even better a way to export the prediction into the last column in the `newdata` .csv?

Comment: To your first comment, yes, you will have to read your new data into the data frame `newmodel` (which is what i am assuming you are naming it as).

Comment: Thanks, but I think I'm still missing one more thing. To create my `bigmodel` object, I used the `mydata` dataset, which is 1707 rows, and my `newmodel` dataset is only 135. If I run my predict function as `predict(bigmodel, newdata = newmodel, type = "p")`, since I'm using `bigmodel` as the object, it's still trying to fit it to 1707 rows, giving me the error `'newdata' had 135 rows but variables found have 1707 rows`. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It should not complain about rows, but it will complain about columns, since you should have all the independent variables in `newmodel`. Can you post some dummy data so we can reproduce your error?

Comment: I have posted a fully reproducible solution using dummy data. Note that `newdata` and `mtcars` have different number of rows.

Comment: Thanks for all the help! I think it has to do with certain blank values being imported to R as blanks instead of `NA`s -- which is something I'm trying to work out here if you can help: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23145430/how-can-i-make-sure-all-my-csv-data-gets-imported-as-na-instead-of-blank-in-r](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23145430/how-can-i-make-sure-all-my-csv-data-gets-imported-as-na-instead-of-blank-in-r) After that gets fixed, I can check to see if this works.